# non-bool value in if condition in Go

Tags: go

I have an if statement in Go which looks like this:

```
if level & 1 {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

The `level` variable in my cause is of type `uint`. But when I do bitwise AND with 1, the result is not a boolean. This is a valid syntax for C, but apparently it doesn't work in Go. Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If statements in Go [must have type of `bool`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements), which you can achieve by using a [comparison operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators), the result of which is a bool:

```
if level&1 != 0 {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: This was arguably the best design decision of the Go language in my opinion. So many bugs avoided